# ShortCode doesn't work when I use custom template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, shortcode

I created custom template "contact.php"

```
contact template
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

And I created a page called contact has only a shortcode in content

```
[wpgmza id="1"]
```

I set template of this page to contact
But I can't see shortcode in real webpage and I don't know the reason.
I tried to call do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="1"]') in template but it also doesn't work.
[image]
[image]
Any advice will be big help.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add echo. Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

`echo do_shortcode( '[wpgmza id="1"]' );`